# Cookiecutter created directory giving me issues running development server and python shell

Tags: python, django, git, shell, cookiecutter

I created a django project using cookiecutter as reccomended by Two scoops of Django 1.8. It's called icecreamratings_project
I use the git cmd prompt and use

'cd icecreamratings_project'.

When i want to use the built-in python interpreter by using
python manage.py shell it gives me the following error. 
File "C:\Users\Armando\Desktop\icecreamratings_project\config\settings\common.py", line 13, in 
    import environ
ImportError: No module named 'environ'

I looked into the directory and the following code is there:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from sys import path

import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (/a/b/myfile.py - 3 = /)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('twoscoops_project')

env = environ.Env()
```

No module named environ exists, but I'm assuming environ is in reference to the virtual environment. Im not familiar with the cookiecutter documentation or how it creates django templates, but i created a virtual environment named environ.

The message i got after that is that there is no Path in environ. Can someone help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `environ` module can be found in [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

`django-environ` is a requirement of [cookiecutter-django's](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) [`requirements/base.txt`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/ec12e84407ebbf762a8020f83e9d3a2e612f357b/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/requirements/base.txt).

`base.txt` is a requirement of [cookiecutter-django's](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) [`requirements/local.txt`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/ec12e84407ebbf762a8020f83e9d3a2e612f357b/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/requirements/local.txt).

It seems you'll install `environ` and other needed modules by completing the following steps from [cookiecutter-django's README.rst](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django#getting-up-and-running):

> ## Getting up and running
>
> The steps below will get you up and running with a local development
>   environment. We assume you have the following installed:
>
> - pip
> - virtualenv
> - PostgreSQL
>
> First make sure to create and activate a virtualenv, then open a
>   terminal at the project root and install the requirements for local
>   development:
>
> ```
> $ pip install -r requirements/local.txt
> ```

Source: https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django#getting-up-and-running

Comment: Worked like a charm!!